# Using `LIKE` inside WHERE clause in Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, where-clause, query-builder

```
public function ajax_quick_browse($keyword) 
{
    if (strlen($keyword) > 3) 
    {
        $results = DB::table("products")
                ->where("full_name", "LIKE", "%{$keyword}%")
                ->take(3)
                ->get();

        if ($results) 
        {
            $output = "";
            foreach ($results as $result) 
            {
                $image_link = $result->brand_name . "-" . str_replace(" ", "-", $result->product_name) . "-" . "thumbnail";
                $image_link = URL::to("/") . "/assets/uploads/" . strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $image_link)) . ".jpg";
                $spec_link = URL::to("/") . "/specification/" . str_singular($result->category_name) . "/{$result->brand_name}/{$result->product_name}/";
                $spec_link = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $spec_link));
                $output .= "<a class='product' href='{$spec_link}'>
                        <ul>
                            <li class='image'><img src='{$image_link}' height='105' width='75' alt='Galaxy S4'></li>
                            <li class='brand'>{$result->brand_name}</li>
                            <li ='model'>{$result->product_name}</li>
                            <li class='status'>{$result->status}</li>
                            <li class='price'>{$result->price} <span class='green'>PKR</span></li>
                        </ul>
                        </a>";
            }
            echo $output;
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "No Results";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The column name is `full_name` which contains a row record `nokia lumia 920`. Now the issue here is that I have three types of keywords as shown..

1. "nokia"
2. "lumia"
3. "920"

When I query with the above two keywords I get result. But when I query with "920" (the last one) keyword I get "No Results".

I am using query builder inside Laravel Framework.

Comment: It may just be a typo, but you would expect nothing with 520 when the row contains 920...

Comment: @RobertSeddon-Smith I corrected typo. Take a look plz.

Comment: can you echo the query and past here?

Comment: I am surprised you get "No Results", because you should be getting nothing. Correct me if I am wrong, strlen(920) is 3, and 3>3 is false.